# Why does an XSLT rendered XML file not print in Internet Explorer?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

I have an XML file with an XSLT stylesheet. Internet Explorer opens and renders the XML file as expected. However, File | Print or File | Print Preview does not show any content. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if your stylesheet has a "@media print" tag that might affect printing?

Answer (score 0):

@phaedra: The stylesheet simply reformats a SOAP response as a tablel it does not have an @media.print tag. I can re-save the data from IE or acquire it with Excel and ALL the data comes across.